# How can I see if every value in an array is less than a certain number?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, bounce

I want the character in my game to move upwards when it is bouncing on a platform. To do this, I calculated the x and y distance between each platform and my character, and then put those values in two arrays: one for the x distance and one for the y distance between them. If the character is on the platform, I want it to move upwards. How can I determine whether a value in the arrays is less than a certain number? I know my code is very inefficient but I don't know how to improve that either.

```
    function loop(e:Event):void{

var plats:Array = new Array();
//adding platforms to array
  plats.push(plat1);
  plats.push(plat2);

//calculating distance between platform and character

var distx1 = Math.sqrt((doodler.x - plat1.x)*(doodler.x - plat1.x));
var disty1 = Math.sqrt(((doodler.y + 50) - plat1.y)*((doodler.y + 50) - plat1.y));
var distx2 = Math.sqrt((doodler.x - plat2.x)*(doodler.x - plat2.x));
var disty2 = Math.sqrt(((doodler.y + 50) - plat2.y)*((doodler.y + 50) - plat2.y));

//adding distance calculations to distance arrays
var disx:Array = new Array();
disx.push(distx1);
disx.push(distx2);

var disy:Array = new Array();
disy.push(disty1);
disy.push(disty2);

  for (var i:int = 0; i < disx.length; i++) {
   //this is where i'm confused
   if(disx[i] < 65 && disy[i] < 3){

      doodler.y -= 100;

       }
```

Comment: Normally you use loops to bulk process data in **Array**s.

Comment: @Organis okay what am i doing wrong

Comment: You are confusing difference between **all** and **any**. Your statement is executed on each and every **i** that satisfies the given conditions. But what you want is to check if **all** of them satisfy the conditions.

Comment: I do want to check if any of the them satisfy the conditions. My current statement is not executing at all right now, which is why I am wondering if there is something wrong with my code. If I output disx[0] and disy[1], both are less than 3, so the character should be moving up, but it is not @Organis

Comment: if i just put one value in the array, it works. but once i added multiple distance values, the character moves down off the screen immediately, since i have this in my code after the if statement: `else{ doodler.y += 5; }`

Answer (score 0):

Difference between **all** and **any**.

```
var aFlag:Boolean = true;

for (var i:int = 0; i < disx.length; i++)
{
    aFlag &&= disx[i] < 65;
    aFlag &&= disy[i] < 3;
}

// At this point, aFlag is true ONLY if
// all the conditions are true at the same time.

if (aFlag)
{
    doodler.y -= 100;
}
```